# sending integer value from controller to view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, exception, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

i am trying to send integer value from controller to view and display in view multiplied by 0.2

here the code in controller

```
public ActionResult Details()
    {

        ViewBag["salary"] = 1400;
        return View();
    }
```

and the code in view

```
@{
Layout = null;


   int Salary=int.Parse(@ViewBag["salary"]);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p> Salary: </p>
        @(Salary / 0.2)
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but it throw an exception

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression
>   of type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code in your controller:

```
ViewBag.salary = 1400;
```

And this code in your view:

```
int Salary=(int)ViewBag.salary;
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the ViewBag is typically considered poor practice, I'd recommend using a Model (Model-View-Controller).  I'll also mention that adding logic in the view is also poor practice, your logic should be controlled by the Controller.

Model

```
public class DetailsVM
{
  public decimal Salary { get; set ; }
}
```

Controller (method)

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    var model = new DetailsVM();
    model.Salary = 1400 / 0.2;
    return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model DetailsVM
@{
  Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Details</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p> Salary: </p>
    @Model.Salary
</div>
</body>
</html>
```