# Insert data using foreign key in asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have some documents in document table of my postgres database. Now, I want to fetch and insert document in transmittal table using foreign key.

Currently, I can see all documents in `TransmittalDocument.cshtml` page, but `transmittal_no` is not populated perfectly.

As It should be `1,2,3,4,5,6,40,50 etc`. If I am in transmittal no 40. All value of row should be `40` for line of code:

```
<td>
    <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area=""
     asp-controller="TransmittalStructure" 
     asp-action="StructureIndex">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.transmittal_no)
     </a>
</td>.
```

Because If transmittal_no is not right, document will not insert in transmittal table with foreign key. That is my perspective. May I am wrong too. So, Please guide me.

[Tried Link sending integer value from controller to view in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138624/sending-integer-value-from-controller-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc)

1. Controller :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TransmittalDocument(int transmittal_no)
    {
        List<DocumentModel>? dModel = new List<DocumentModel>();
        ViewBag.TransmittalNo = transmittal_no;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage getData = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(baseURL + "Document"));
            if (getData.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var results = await getData.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                dModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DocumentModel>>(results);
                var document_no = dModel[dModel.Count - 1].document_no;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error calling API");
            }
        }
        return View(dModel);
    }
```

2. Models :

```
namespace corrsmanagment_usingvscode.Models
{
    public class TransmittalModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int transmittal_no { get; set; }
        public string? subject { get; set; }
        public string? classification { get; set; }
        public string? receipt_distribution_list { get; set; }
        public DateTime? scheduledate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? acknowledgement_date { get; set; }
        public string? comment { get; set; }
        public bool isNewRecord { get; set; }

        public string? cpers_name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? cdate { get; set; }
        public string? mpers_name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? last_mdate { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Document")] //------ fetching document using foreign key
        public int? document_no { get; set; }
        public virtual DocumentModel? Document { get; set; }

    }
}

namespace corrsmanagment_usingvscode.Models
{
    public class DocumentModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int document_no { get; set; }
        public string? index_value { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("title")]
        public string? title { get; set; }
        public string? category_name { get; set; }
        public string? subcategory_name { get; set; }
        public string? author { get; set; }
        public string? origin { get; set; }
        public string? dept_name { get; set; }
        public string? keywords { get; set; }
        public string? remarks { get; set; }
        public string? doc_status { get; set; }
        public string? lock_name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Transmittal")] //------ fetching transmittal using foreign key
        public int transmittal_no { get; set; }
        public virtual TransmittalModel? TransmittalM { get; set; }
    }
}
```

3. View : TransmittalDocument.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<corrsmanagment_usingvscode.Models.DocumentModel>

@{
    int transmittalNo = (int)ViewBag.TransmittalNo;
}

<div class="fixTableHead">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-row" style="text-align: center;" >
                <th class="table-header-col"><input type="checkbox"></th>
                <th class="table-header-srno" scope="col" style="width: fit-content;">@Html.DisplayName("Transmittal No")</th>
                <th class="table-header-srno" scope="col" style="width: fit-content;">@Html.DisplayName("Document No")</th>
                <th class="table-header-rfiid" scope="col">@Html.DisplayName("Title")</th>
                <th class="table-header-package" scope="col">@Html.DisplayName("Category Name")</th>
                <th class="table-header-package" scope="col">@Html.DisplayName("Sub Category Name")</th>
                <th class="table-header-package" scope="col">@Html.DisplayName("Author")</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody class="table-tablebody">
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                @foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(x => x.document_no))
                {
                    <tr>
                        @if (transmittalNo != null) // Add null check for item.TransmittalM
                        {
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><input type="checkbox"></td>
                            <td><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="TransmittalStructure" asp-action="StructureIndex">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.transmittal_no)</a></td>
                            <td><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Transmittal" asp-action="TransmittalDocument" asp-route-id="@item.document_no">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.document_no)</a></td>
                            <td><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="TransmittalStructure" asp-action="StructureIndex">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title)</a></td>
                            <td><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="TransmittalStructure" asp-action="StructureIndex">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.category_name)</a></td>
                            <td><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="TransmittalStructure" asp-action="StructureIndex">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.subcategory_name)</a></td>
                            <td><a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="TransmittalStructure" asp-action="StructureIndex">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.author)</a></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center">
                                <form method="post">
                                    <a asp-controller="Transmittal" asp-action="InsertDocument" asp-route-transmittal_no="@item.transmittal_no" class="btn btn-safe" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Add?')">Add Document</a>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            }
            else
            {
                <p>No documents found.</p>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

1. I had tried to pass transmittal_no from the MainIndex page, where I can see all the transmittal details.
2. To Insert document, tried below method. with passing of transmittal_no as a parameter.

```
public IActionResult Documents(List<TransmittalModel> model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> InsertDocument(int transmittal_no, int document_no)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                // Step 1: Send an HTTP GET request to fetch the transmittal by its ID
                var transmittalResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(baseURL + "Transmittal/" + transmittal_no);
                transmittalResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Ensure a successful response

                // Step 2: Deserialize the transmittal from the response
                var transmittalResult = await transmittalResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var transmittal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransmittalModel>(transmittalResult);

                // Step 3: Send an HTTP GET request to fetch the document by its ID
                var documentResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(baseURL + "Document/" + document_no);
                documentResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Ensure a successful response

                // Step 4: Deserialize the document from the response
                var documentResult = await documentResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var document = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentModel>(documentResult);

                // Step 5: Prepare the updated transmittal model with the new document
                var updatedTransmittal = new TransmittalModel
                {
                    transmittal_no = transmittal.transmittal_no,
                    document_no = document_no,
                    Document = document
                };

                // Step 6: Send an HTTP PUT request to update the transmittal with the new document
                var updatedTransmittalJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updatedTransmittal);
                var content = new StringContent(updatedTransmittalJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var updateResponse = await httpClient.PutAsync(baseURL + "Transmittal/UpdateTransmittal/" + transmittal_no, content);
                updateResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Ensure a successful response

                // Step 7: Pass the updated TransmittalModel to the view for further processing
                return View("Documents", updatedTransmittal);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                // Handle API request errors
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Error: " + ex.Message;
                return View("Documents");
            }
        }
    }
```